# How to conventiently pass around global settings which can be modified

Tags: python, design-patterns

I often find myself writing code that takes a set of parameters, does some calculalation and then returns the result to another function, which also requires some of the parameters to do some other manipulation, and so on. I end up with a lot of functions where I have to pass around parameters, such as `f(x, y, N, epsilon)` which then calls `g(y, N, epsilon)` and so on. All the while I have to include the parameters `N` and `epsilon` in every function call and not lose track of them, which is quite tedious.

What I want is to prevent this endlessly passing around of parameters, while still being able to, within a single `for` loop, to change some of these parameters, e.g.

```
for epsilon in [1,2,3]:
    f(..., epsilon)
```

I usually have around 10 parameters to keep track of (these are physics problems) and do not know beforehand which I have to vary and which I can keep to a default.

The options I thought of are

1. Creating a global `settings = {'epsilon': 1, 'N': 100}` object, which is used by every function. However, I have always been told that putting stuff in the global namespace is bad. I am also afraid that this will not play nice with modifying the `settings` object within the `for` loop.
2. Passing around a `settings` object as a parameter in every function. This means that I can keep track of the object as it passed around, and makes it play nice with the `for` loop. However, it is still passing around, which seems stupid to me.

Is there another, third, option that I have not considered? Most of the solution I can find are for the case where your settings are only set once, as you start up the program, and are then unchanged.

Comment: If you mostly work on the same set of parameters, create a class around the functions manipulating them and set them once in the init function of this class. If needed, the class can also read a configuration file of parameters that are used in a more global scope.

Comment: Interesting, I had not considered that. However, I would prefer to stay away from an OOP solution, especially since I have the same problem in languages where OOP is not supported, such as Julia.

Answer (score 1):

I believe this is primarily a matter of preference among coding styles. I'm going to offer my opinion on the ones you posted as well as some other alternatives.

First, creating a global settings variable is not bad by itself. Problems arise if global settings are treated as mutable state rather than being immutable. As you want to modify parameters on the fly it's a dangerous option.

Second, passing the settings around is quite common in functional languages and it's not stupid although it can look clumsy if you're not used to it. The advantage of passing state this way is that you can isolate changes in the dictionary settings you pass around without corrupting the original one, the bad thing is that python messes a bit with immutability because of shared references and you can end up making many deepcopy's to prevent data races, which is totally inefficient. Unless your dict is not nested I would not go that way.

```
settings = {'epsilon': 1, 'N': 100}

# Unsafe but OK for plain dict
for x in [1, 2, 3]:
    f(..., dict(zip(settings, ('epsilon', x))))

# Safe way. 
ephimeral = copy.deepcopy(settings)
for x in [1, 2, 3]:
    ephimeral['epsilon'] = x
    f(..., ephimeral)
```

Now, there's another option which kind of mixes the other two, probably the one I'll take. Make a global immutable settings variable and write your functions signatures to accept optional keyword arguments. This way you have the advantages of both, ability to avoid continuous variable passing and ability to modify on the fly values without data races:

```
def f(..., **kwargs):
    epsilon = kwargs.get('epsilon', settings['epsilon'])
    ...
```

You may also create a function that encapsulates the aforementioned behavior to decouple variable extraction from function definition. There are many possibilities.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks, the global immutable settings sounds like a good idea. I do not really like this idea of continuously passing around a `**kwargs` argument, but I suppose it has to make do.